# Something dongle-sized to enable wifi net connection to ethernet modem?

Tags: wireless-networking

I currently connect my laptop to the internet using an ethernet modem. I want to continue to do this most of the time, but occasionally to connect wirelessly, by plugging something as small as possible into the existing modem and then using my laptop, which is 802.11ac enabled, in another part of the house. I know I can get a wifi router and plug it into the ethernet modem, but instead of using one of those I want to use a bit of kit that's much smaller, dongle-sized if possible.

Would the following work?

1) Plug a male-RJ45-to-female-USB connector into the modem, and then

2) plug a male-USB wifi dongle into the said connector.

I'm hoping the answer is "yes", so that I can leave these two small pieces of kit plugged together and then just plug the RJ45 end (instead of the RJ45 cable) into the modem when I want to wander with the laptop.

Comment: No, it definitely won't work. You can't connect one USB device to another USB device. USB is, fundamentally, a host-to-device link.

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution for keeping the whole setup physically small would be to get a small home gateway that includes the kind of broadband modem you need and has Wi-Fi AP (wireless router) functionality built in.

Or, if you really like your current broadband modem, buy a very small "travel router" type Wi-Fi AP and make a short Ethernet cable to connect it to the Ethernet port of the modem. Consider the TP-LINK TL-WR7xxN models, such as the TL-WR702N.

Here are some reasons why your dongle won't work:

1. Your broadband modem almost certainly does not provide Power over Ethernet (PoE), so no pure dongle is possible; whatever device you get will have to have its own way to connect to power.
2. There is no such thing as "a male-RJ45-to-female-USB connector". Part of this is because RJ-45 Males break too easily, so no one builds them into a captive cable. But there is no such thing as an Ethernet female-RJ-45-to-female-USB-A connector" either. If you've seen a device that looks like that, it's half of a matched set: a USB-over-Cat5 extender, which does proprietary signaling over the Cat5 cable, not Ethernet. So the device you may have seen wouldn't be able to talk to the Ethernet port on your broadband modem.
3. There is no such thing as a generic USB-A host port (female) device that connects to Ethernet. USB can be used for tons of different things, and it would be very difficult to make a general-purpose Ethernet-connected USB host port, where people could buy any arbitrary USB device and connect it up to that Ethernet-connected host port device and have any hope of being able to share it on the network in any meaningful way. There are single-purpose boxes like USB print servers or NAS servers for sharing USB external hard drives, but no general-purpose "USB servers", and even if there were, your modem wouldn't be able to run the client software to connect to it. There are no single-purpose Ethernet-connected devices for sharing USB Wi-Fi dongles, and even if there were, again your modem wouldn't be able to run the client software to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a look at the travel routers you suggest. On the power question (1), I could use a powered USB hub, although the size of the whole caboodle would be approaching the size of a router, so it might not be worth it. (2) - what's [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/161324078636) then? :) (Male RJ45 to female USB.) (3) I don't properly understand. The signal comes out of the Ethernet socket. What is the problem (other than power) with grabbing it and then throwing it out using a USB wifi dongle? Excuse my ignorance and thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: I've now looked at the TL-WR702N, which seems nice and small, but I'd have to power it off the mains, which means another cable, so I'm considering the suggestion you make in your first sentence. Is there such a thing as an Ethernet broadband modem that has wifi functionality that can be switched on and off?

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work - for 2 reasons
1.  The WIFI settings won't be configured on the modem side.
2.  The modem side USB device is an AP Client, as is the computer, you need
    to talk to an AP device (unless your modem is very smart and can turn
    it into an AP - this is theoretically possible, but if your modem had
    the smarts to do it, it would not be a WIFI enabled router !)

Have you considered replacing your modem with a router with WIFI built in ?